# Why the website cannot be accessed without www?

Tags: linux, http, networking, web

For example, if I just visit `example.com` the website cannot be visited. Instead, I have to explicitly use `www.example.com` in order to access it correctly, which fact turns out to be annoying since people don't really want to type `www` all the time. What's the solution here? I'm using linux servers.

Comment: from an external machine, where dig or nslookup are installed, what's the output of `dig @8.8.8.8 www.XXX.com` and/or `nslookup www.XXX.com 8.8.8.8` this will check agains google dns, and ofcourse, if you recently added www subdomain to your dns, it could take some time to propagate

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `A` record on your `dns service provider`, and the host name should be `www`. just like this:
[image]

first column is the `host name`, second is `record type`, ignore the third  and the last one (different provider differs), the fourth is `ip address`, pointing to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is no DNS A Record for the www subdomain.

You need to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I think OneZero wants the naked domain to either works directly by entering `example.com` alone, or automatically redirect to `www.example.com`.

First you need to define a naked domain A Record (example.com), the IP is probably the same as www.example.com, eg in the BIND zone file:

```
example.com.          IN    A   123.123.123.123
www.example.com.      IN    A   123.123.123.123
```

Then you can use your web server to redirect to `www.example.com`, for example in Apache use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```